# can we call factory method using ng-click from HTML?

Tags: angularjs

Requirenment is to call the factory method directly from ng-click is it possible ?

```
ng-click="viewDocument(documentData.docId)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you bind the factory to your scope like so:

```
$scope.factory = myFactory;
```

and then in your template:

```
ng-click="myFactory.viewDocument(documentData.docId)"
```

or directly bind the function to your scope:

```
$scope.viewDocument = myFactory.viewDocument;
```

and in your template:

```
ng-click="viewDocument(documentData.docId)"
```